# Save Excel file in SAP GUI with Python

Tags: python, pywin32, pyautogui, sap-gui, sap-erp

I'm writing a Python script that automates the process of extracting a file in SAP GUI. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to save this file to a specific directory on my computer with the name "ME3L".

How can I accomplish this in my code?

Here's my current code:

```
import pyautogui
import time

# Abrir o SAP GUI
pyautogui.press('win')
pyautogui.write('SAP Logn')
pyautogui.press('enter')

# Esperar o SAP GUI abrir
time.sleep(2)

# Fazer login
pyautogui.press('enter')

# Esperar o SAP GUI carregar
time.sleep(3)

pyautogui.write('Rodriguesk')
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.write('AbrtoRio89@')
pyautogui.press('enter')

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.write('ME3L')
pyautogui.press('enter')

time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.hotkey('shift', 'f5')

for i in range(2):
    pyautogui.press('down')

for i in range(11):
    pyautogui.press('delete')
pyautogui.press('f8')

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.press('down')
pyautogui.press('f2')

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.press('f8')

time.sleep(22)

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','f9')
pyautogui.press('tab')
for i in range(6):
    pyautogui.press('down')
pyautogui.press('enter')

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','shift','F7')
pyautogui.press('enter')

time.sleep(4)
```

I try use chatgpt, but he dont gave a solution.

Comment: At least ChatGPT masters grammar (at least in this case), with explanations: *"What is the correct version of "I try use chatgpt, but he dont gave a solution."?"*. Response: *"The correct version of the sentence would be: "I tried to use ChatGPT, but it didn't provide a solution.". Here are a few explanations for the corrections: 1. "tried" should be used instead of "try" because it indicates that the action was attempted in the past. 2. "to use" is the correct form of the infinitive to follow "tried." 3. "ChatGPT" should be capitalized as it is a proper noun."*

Comment: cont' - *"4. "didn't" is the contraction for "did not," which is the correct negative form for the past tense of "do." 5. "provided" is a better verb choice than "gave" in this context. 6. Lastly, the pronoun "he" should be replaced with "it" to refer to ChatGPT since it is an AI language model and not a person."*

Comment: Though it could have included an explanation of [present simple tense, third person singular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=0m38s).

Comment: You are asking "how to save to a directory" but you don't explain what your script currently does, what is failing, etc.